# "To latch in a recess/groove" vs. "to catch in a recess/groove"

Tags: meaning, differences, verbs, technical

Is there a difference in meaning when used in a technical context? For example, does a fork latch in a recess when pressed or does it catch in the recess?

Comment: Depends entirely on the "technical context" -- English language only defines the verbs *latch* and *catch* as in the dictionaries.

Comment: If something isn't holding the fork in place in the recess, I would say that the fork "catches" in the recess. "Catches" here is a synonym for "snags; gets stuck." To be of better help, can you give some more description of the fork and the recess.

Comment: The context is: mounting instructions for hardware for sliding doors made of glass. I have written: "Tension the dampers of the damper and soft closing device.
To do this, push the driving forks into the end position until they catch in the recess." (The expression "damper and soft closing device" is fixed and prescribed by the customer.)Is this description understandable with accompanying pictures / drawings?

Answer (score 2):

"settles" in a groove has a more permanent connotation than "catches" in a groove, which, to me, seems more like "snags".

Answer (score 0):

The verb *latch* is today used only with *on* following it, not with *in*, like:

> Once you latch on to some hare-brained scheme, you never let go, do you?

The OED says that using *latch* to mean to catch in something like a receptacle is now obsolete or dialectal, and provides these old examples:

> - 1601 Holland *Pliny* I. 301 ― Vnlesse there be good heed taken that the eggs be latched in some soft bed vnder‐neath, they are soone broken.
> - 1639 Horn & Rob. *Gate Lang. Unl.* xxxv. §415 ― A dairy-maid milketh out milk latching it in a milk-paile.
> - 1639 Horn & Rob. *Gate Lang. Unl.* xli. §445 ― The droppings, or any thing else spilt by chance, is latcht in a latch-pan.

There is another dialectal use meaning to alight or settle, as in:

> - 1871 *East Anglian* IV. 111 ― The Golden crested Wren, often caught by the hand while ‘latching’ in the rigging.

I strongly encourage you to use *catch* here, not *latch*, unless you are trying to represent dialect or archaic speech.

Comment: What if he wants to say that a latch holds the fork in place?

Comment: @tylerharms That is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: I know. A latch. But doesn't a latch latch shut?

Comment: I don't think [it latches into](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22it+latches+into%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is at all archaic/dialectal when it means "connects securely" (of a fastening, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Surely "latch in" ≠ "latch into". Please check your OED2 for ***latch*** (*verb* 1), and see  whether you disagree with any of that.

Comment: I don't disagree with OED's definitions. Sense **3** *To catch (something falling); to catch or receive in (a receptacle).* is indeed obsolete/archaic. I'm just saying you can't be that absolutist about what prepositions are "valid" with current senses.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no mechanism that holds the forks in place, if they just stay fast by design, I would use the passive construction "are secured."

"Until the forks *are secured* in the recess" makes it clear that, by whatever method of retention, the forks maintain their position in the recess.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So far as I'm concerned, the *brackets* there (the horizontal supports under each shelf) **latch into** the *standards* (the long vertical slotted strips fastened to the wall).

In this particular example there are lots of "recesses/grooves" in the uprights. But in, say, a [track lighting system](http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?hl=en&tbo=d&biw=1329&bih=866&tbm=isch&tbnid=aqgEgR66cOkBeM:&imgrefurl=http://www.aliexpress.com/compare/compare-install-track-lighting.html&docid=pdGpv4AE9oN76M&itg=1&imgurl=http://i00.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/639101458/Wonderful-font-b-Lighting-b-font-Effect-Export-Europe-HID-Special-font-b-Track-b-font.jpg&w=800&h=497&ei=lQe1UO6jGsmo0QXjrYHwCg&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=4&vpy=155&dur=3604&hovh=177&hovw=285&tx=141&ty=109&sig=113655182887642520613&page=1&tbnh=129&tbnw=186&start=0&ndsp=36&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:82), the bulb holder may fit into an extended groove - in which case you normally *latch it in* by pushing it in in one orientation, then twisting it by 90° to secure it.

[Here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22which%20latches%20into%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are some written instances of *"which latches into"*, where in most cases it's fairly obviously describing some physical component being "locked" into a position within an assembly.

---

To my way of thinking, *catch* usually implies *inadvertently get caught up/snagged*, so I wouldn't use that word in OP's context, where *latch, lock, click, snap* are all reasonable alternatives.

Having said that, in the "negative" version of OP's example, I think *catch* can actually work better. Suppose he's trying to secure his "locking fork" into the "locating recess" - but failing because of clumsiness / manufacturing defects / worn parts / whatever. In that case, he could quite reasonably say *"Fiddlesticks! I can't get the fork to **catch** in the slot!"*

Comment: A latch is a specific closure requiring a securing arm. See this quite old image of a latch: http://www.meadowforge.co.uk/upcot%20barton%20door%20latch001.JPG The shelving brackets use grooves, and the shelving arms are just designed to fit securely in the grooves. There is no latching action. The word needs to describe that fastening action the arm makes when locking into the groove.

Comment: @tylerharms: That's just your opinion. As I said in my answer, *so far as I'm concerned*, there are lots of "fastenings" involving two components that can easily be brought together, where the "locking" process can reasonably be described as "latching". I certainly don't need dictionaries or Google to tell me what "a latch" is.

Comment: It's definitely not my opinion that a latch uses a securing arm to hold something in place. If you asked for a shelf that attached with a latch or by latching, you would not get a shelf that snapped  or slid into place. As per one of your examples: "A tumbler usually consists of a small lever, one end of which has a little projection, which latches into a notch cut into the bolt, and is kept down by a spring." This describes a latch arm. The OP is asking about something that doesn't use any kind of arm to hold something in place. The thing just sticks.

Comment: @tylerharms: We seem to be at cross purposes. I *know* that one half of a fastening called "a latch" can often be described as "a securing arm". That's got no real relevance to other uses of the word "latch". You wouldn't use the word "arm", for example, when talking about a [Yale lock](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Yale+lock), but that particular "fastener" is always being [left on the latch](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22left+on+the+latch%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: No, you probably wouldn't, but I don't think door locks where you throw the bolt with a key or a turning knob are technically latches--and apparently, amazingly, EL&U has a post about it--although we use "left on the latch." cheers.